# Debugging with GDB - set an Ada array value

Tags: arrays, gdb, ada, gnat-gps

Im trying to set a value in specific cell in an array,
but no matter what i do the value doesn't change.
I'v tried use "set var array(1) = 1" but it didn't do anything.
Does any one have idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You’re debugging in Ada mode, so you need to use an Ada assignment.

The variable can’t be called `array`, because that’s a reserved word, but assuming it’s `A` then

```
set var a(1) := 1
```

should do the trick.

The `var` is needed; and square brackets (`a[1]`) work too.

Additionally, have you compiled with a low optimisation level? (`-O0`, for example). The previous value of the array element might have been cached in a register.